# Vertical align after wrapping text

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, alignment

I have a list of table with 2 columns.

The list width is fixed.
The first column contains text wrapping if to long.
The second column will contains an image (for the sample is text)

I would like to have the second TD verticaly align at the middle and near the first TD with text wrapped if too long.

like this :
.....................................................
|Gestion des |                                 |
|utilisateurs   | coucou                  |
.....................................................
|Gestion | Coucou                        |
.....................................................
|BLA bla bla bla bla     |                |
|bla bla bla bla bla bla |coucou     |
bla bla bla bla bla        |                |
.....................................................

The sample : 
http://jsfiddle.net/3db8U/

The problem is in the first line of my list

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe you want the 2nd cell (with an image) to be vertically aligned to the top?

you can set the 2nd `td` style to `vertical-align:top` like so

```
<tr cellpadding="0" >
    <td>...</td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top">
        <a href="#sub5-1">coucou</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/3db8U/1/)

Comment: no I want the 2nd cell vertically aligned to the middle and near the first cell with wrapping text due to the max width of my list

Answer (score 0):

If the text in the first column should also be in the middle, use this:

```
table { table-layout:fixed; }
table td { vertical-align:middle; word-wrap:break-word; }
```

Otherwise, also give it a class and override like so:

```
table td.firstcolumn { vertical-align:top; }
```

Or use the `:first-child` selector: (but browser support is still pretty scarce for this)

```
table td:first-child { vertical-align:top; }
```

Comment: I want to align the second TD at the middle vertically and near the first column.

Comment: it's doesn't work. I change with your code, but it's change nothing --> http://jsfiddle.net/3db8U/8/ . I want the second text at the middle, not on top and near the first text